# Can't modify subgrid in Dynamics 365 Ribbon workbench

Tags: crm-ribbon-workbench

I'm using Dynamics 365 Ribbon Workbench, but for few of my custom entities, the subgrid ribbon is empty.
Home and form ribbon can be changed, but not Subgrid. It just seem empty.

Anyone knows if I'm missing a configuration, either in Dynamics or Ribbon workbench?

[image: Screenshot of missing ribbon]

Comment: Is this happening for all entities, only this particular entity, different environments? You can try XrmToolbox ribbon workbench to see any version issues or try importing RWB managed solution into CRM

Answer (score 0):

We have exactly the same issue. In our RWB solution we had an entity that had a word "information" in it.
In one of the CRM forum posts [link below], it was said that Scott D. [RWB Developer] stated that SubGrid buttons in RWB solution do tend to disappear [or rather move into the either Home or Form grid] if the entity name contains word "information" in it.

[CRM Forum](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/212399/sub-grid-is-missing-in-ribbon-workbench?pifragment-97030=1)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why the buttons have moved to Form Command Bar.
I also do not think that the name has anything to do with this. In the screenshot below you can see in the top left corner that the entity's logical name does not contain the word "information" in it.

[image: displaced buttons in ribbon work bench]

Although the ribbon workbench buttons appear displaced, they still appear on the sub-grid once you open Dynamics 365 UCI. This means you can still add customizations irrespective of where the ribbon workbench shows them.

I found the buttons on the Form Grid's right-hand side in the ribbon workbench. You just need to scroll a little bit to the right.